# VBA Copying a Pasting to Sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

Need to open a set of locked work books and copy and past data sets and relock and close the work books. Everything is working fine, but the data will not paste into the new work book not sure what is going on.

I know it is copying the data but not sure why it will not paste. I have tried it on local files and SharePoint and neither is working
Below is the code:

```
Sub exportdata()

'Basic Parameters for entire code

'Timer to measure total macro run time

    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim MinutesElapsed As String
    StartTime = Timer
    
    Dim Data_Export As Workbook
    Set Data_Export = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim Data_Location As Worksheet
    Set Data_Location = Data_Export.Sheets("Data_Location")
    
    Dim PS_ROllOUT As Worksheet
    Set PS_ROllOUT = Data_Export.Sheets("Export_Data")
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Step 1: Code to open up store review workbooks (set up as a loop)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To Application.CountA(Data_Location.Range("D:D"))
    
    Application.StatusBar = "Current iteration: " & i - 1 & " of " & Application.CountA(Data_Location.Range("D2:D100")) & " - " & Data_Location.Range("A" & i)
    
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Data_Location.Range("D" & i).Value, ReadOnly:=False, notify:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                
         '''Code below opens workbook and requires user to manually accept read only version
         'Workbooks.Open Filename:=Data_Location.Range("D" & i)

    On Error Resume Next

'Step 2: Unlocking workbook and bud table

    Dim Factory_BUD As Workbook
    Set Factory_BUD = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Factory_BUD.Unprotect "bud"
    Worksheets("Export_Data").Visible = True
    Worksheets("Export_Data").Unprotect "bud"
    
    Dim Export_Data As Worksheet
    Set Export_Data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Export_Data")


'step 3 : Copy Budtable Data

    PS_ROllOUT.Activate
    Range("A1:AH1000").Copy
    
    Export_Data.Activate
    Worksheets("Export_Data").Select
    Range("A1").Select.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'step4: Close and lock workbooks

    Factory_BUD.Activate
    Worksheets("Export_Data").Protect "bud"
    Worksheets("Export_Data").Visible = False
    Factory_BUD.Protect "bud"
    Factory_BUD.Close SaveChanges = True
    
    Next i
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = False
    PS_ROllOUT.Activate
    
    MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
    
    
    MsgBox ("Rollup Budget Updated" & vbNewLine & _
            "Total run time: " & MinutesElapsed & " minutes"), vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Comment the `On Error Resume Next` line, step into the code with `F8` key and report back. Also add `Option Explicit` at the top of the module. Your code doesn't compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my approach.

Some suggestions:

- Use `option explicit` at the top of your modules so you don't have unexpected behavior with undefined variables
- Always indent your code (see [www.rubberduckvba.com][1] a free tool that helps you with that)
- Try to separate your logic defining variables and the reusing them
- Name your variables to something meaningful and easy to unterstand (avoid i or x)
- Write the code steps in plain English first, then develop it in VBA (you already have somethig)
- Check the code's comments, and adapt it to fit your needs

**NOTE:** I <s>strongly</s> suggest that you validate some things like if the workbook opened and the worksheet exists.

### Code

```
Public Sub ExportDataToSP()

    ' Basic error handling
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    
    ' Turn off stuff
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Timer: to measure total macro run time
    Dim startTime As Double
    Dim minutesElapsed As String
    startTime = Timer
    
    ' Set data export references
    Dim dataExportWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim dataExportSheet As Worksheet
    Set dataExportWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    Set dataExportSheet = dataExportWorkbook.Worksheets("Export_Data")
    
    ' Set data location references
    Dim dataLocationSheet As Worksheet
    Set dataLocationSheet = dataExportWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_Location")
    
    
    ' Step 1: Code to open up store review workbooks (set up as a loop)
    Dim fileCounter As Long
    Dim totalFiles As Long
    Dim fileInfo As String
    Dim filePath As String
    totalFiles = Application.CountA(dataLocationSheet.Range("D:D"))
    For fileCounter = 2 To totalFiles
        
        ' Gather file data
        fileInfo = dataLocationSheet.Range("A" & fileCounter)
        filePath = dataLocationSheet.Range("D" & fileCounter)
        
        ' Set status bar message
        Application.StatusBar = "Current iteration: " & fileCounter - 1 & " of " & totalFiles & " - " & fileInfo
        
        ' Open target workbook (SharePoint)
        Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filePath, ReadOnly:=False, Notify:=True)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        
        ' Set target sheet in SharePoint workbook
        Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
        Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("Export_Data")
        
        ' Step 2: Unlocking workbook and bud table
        targetWorkbook.Unprotect "bud"
        targetSheet.Visible = True
        targetSheet.Unprotect "bud"
        
        ' Set data export range
        Dim dataExportRange As Range
        Set dataExportRange = dataExportSheet.Range("A1:AH1000")
        
        ' Step 3: Copy Bud table Data (Values)
        targetSheet.Range("A1").Resize(dataExportRange.Rows.Count, dataExportRange.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = dataExportRange.Cells.Value
        
        ' Step 4: Close and lock workbooks
        targetSheet.Protect "bud"
        targetSheet.Visible = False
        targetWorkbook.Protect "bud"
        targetWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
        
    Next fileCounter
    
    ' Timer: Display elapsed time
    minutesElapsed = Format((Timer - startTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
    MsgBox ("Rollup Budget Updated" & vbNewLine & _
            "Total run time: " & minutesElapsed & " minutes"), vbInformation
            
CleanExit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Exit Sub
 
CleanFail:
    Debug.Print "Something went wrong: " & Err.Description
    Resume CleanExit
            
End Sub
```

Let me know if it works